# Linux active directory tool

Tags: linux, active-directory

Are there any useful tools for linux to work with active directory.
I am looking for something analogous to active directory users and computers or AD Explorer.

As far as ADUC is concerned, is it only dealing with LDAP or are there other protocols being used. Was wondering if it worth writing my own tool...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have a mix of AD and OpenLDAP in our environment and we use the same LDAP tools to connect to both of them.  While it is a little large for an LDAP browser (it is Eclipse-based), I am a fan of [Apache's Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/).

Comment: +1 to comment. I work in a large AD/OD environment and ADS is my best friend. Also use adtool as mentioned by AlberT. Take note however that some AD fields may not be editable via LDAP since they are not actual LDAP properties but rather calculated on the fly (can't remember the attribute atm). Both ADS and adtool will suffer from this little setback. But it's only very few attributes.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK AD is a mix of LDAP and Kerberos, so an LDAP client should be adapted in principle

Could ***[ADtool](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/08/02/manage-your-active-directory-from-linux-with-adtool/)*** be your friend?